# Troubles in MPI -> Failing at address: (nil)

Tags: c, matrix, mpi, null, openmpi

I'm a beginner in C and MPI and i'm trying to do a program to multiply 2 matrix in MPI. 
But I don't kwno what is wrong in my code.
I'm try do 'slice' the matrix M1 in n lines and send then to another process do multiply and broadcast de matrix M2 After I make a Gather to build the final matrix M3.
I make this:

```
mpirun -n 2 matrix
```

But I receive a error in terminal:

```
[adiel-VirtualBox:07921] *** Process received signal ***
[adiel-VirtualBox:07921] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[adiel-VirtualBox:07921] Signal code:  (128)
[adiel-VirtualBox:07921] Failing at address: (nil)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 7921 on node adiel-VirtualBox exited on signal 0 (Unknown signal 0).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
2 total processes killed (some possibly by mpirun during cleanup)
mpirun: clean termination accomplished
```

Can anyone help me?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"
//#include "mpe.h"
#include <math.h>


void printMatrix(double *M, int m, int n) {
   int lin, col;
   for (lin=0; lin<m; lin++) {
      for (col=0; col<n; col++)
        printf("%.2f \t", M[(lin*n+col)]);
      printf("\n"); 
   }
}

double* allocateMatrix(int m, int n){
    double* M;
    M = (double *)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
    return M;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    int rank, size;
    int m1,n1,m2,n2;
    int row, col,ctrl,i,k,lines,proc;
    double *M1, *M2, *M3, **vp, *v;

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
    MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );

    m1 = m2 = n1 = n2 = 3;

    lines = (int)ceil(n1/size);
    v = (double *)malloc(lines*n1*sizeof(double));


    M2 = allocateMatrix(m2,n2);
    M3 = allocateMatrix(m1,n2);
if(rank==0)
    M1 = allocateMatrix(m1,n1);

    //startin matrix
    for (col = 0; col < n1; col++){
        for (row = 0; row < m1; row++) {
            if(rank==0)
            M1[(row*m1+col)] = 0;
            M2[(row*m2+col)] = 0;
            M3[(row*m1+col)] = 0;
        }
    }
//startin pointers with 0
for(i=0;i<lines*n1;i++)
v[i] = 0;

    //populate
    if(rank == 0){
        for (col = 0; col < n1; col++){
            for (row = 0; row < m1; row++) {
                M1[row*m1+col] = row*3+(col+1);
                M2[(row*m2+col)] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

//---------------------sharing and multiply---------------//


    //slicing M1 and sending to other process
    if(rank == 0){
        proc = size-1;
        //for each line
        for(row = 0;row<m1;row++){
        ctrl = floor(row/lines);            
            //on each column
            for(col=0;col<n1;col++){
                v[(ctrl*n1)+col] = M1[(row*n1)+col];
            }
            if(row%lines == (lines - 1)){
                if(proc!=0){
                    MPI_Send(v,lines*n1,MPI_DOUBLE,proc,1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    proc--;
                    //clearing pointers
                    for(i=0;i<lines*n1;i++)
                        v[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //MPI_Bcast(m1, m*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    MPI_Bcast(M2, m2*n2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 


    //receiving process
    if(rank!=0)
        MPI_Recv(v,lines*n1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            for(row=0;row<lines;row++){
                if(v[row*n1]!=0){
                    for (col = 0; col < n1; col++){
                    double val = 0.0;
                        for(k=0;k<m1;k++){
                            val += v[(row*n1)+k] * M2[(k*n1)+col];
                        }
                        M3[((size-1-rank)*size*n1)+(row*n1)+col] = val;
                    }
                }
            }


    if(rank!=0){    
        for(row = 0; row < lines; row++){
            MPI_Gather(&M3[((size-1-rank)*size*n1)+(row*n1)], n1, MPI_DOUBLE, &M3[((size-1-rank)*size*n1)+(row*n1)], n1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
        }   
    }

if(rank == 0){  
printf("matrix 1------------------------\n");
printMatrix(M1,m1,n1); 
printf("matrix 2------------------------\n");
printMatrix(M2,m2,n2);
printf("matrix 3------------------------\n");
printMatrix(M3,m1,n2);
}
  MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this just comes from misunderstanding integer arithmetic in dividing up your problem.  You have `n1 = 3; lines = (int)ceil(n1/size);` but `n1` and `size` (2 here) are integers, so the ceil doesn't do anything; `3/2 == 1` in integer arithmetic, so you don't allocate your `v[]` array large enough.  And then you write past its bounds it in your send loop and you end up in trouble.   If you want to round up in integer arithmetic, use, eg, `lines == (n1 + size - 1)/size`.  Your loop over send/recvs would also better be done by an `MPI_Scatterv`, and I'm puzzled by your use of `MPI_Gather`.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, doing all of your sends before the broadcast, and all of the receives after it is asking for trouble. I can easily see that leading to MPI resource exhaustion or deadlock failures. In such a small input that shouldn't arise, but you should fix it regardless. I'll take another look after that.